# Count number of configured return values in NSubstitute

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

In NSubstitute, I can configure return values as so:

```
someClass.SomeMethod(Arg.Is<int>)
      .Returns(1,2,3,4,5);
```

and I can count the number of received calls using `...ReceivedCalls.Count()`, for example.

What I want to do is count the number of *configured* calls. i.e. how many values have I supplied to the `Returns()` method above?

Is this possible?